# Accessing Share on 2008 R2 server from XP workstation

Tags: windows-server-2008

The scenario:
We have a one-way cross forest trust with selective auth with another agency. Both forests are 2008 R2. We are the trusted domain so our users can access a file server on their network.
Everything works great from Windows 7 clients. None of our XP clients or 2003 servers can access the share. We have opened the ports in the firewalls as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179442)
. A net use just comes back with the network path cannot be found.

I have disabled Netbois on an XP client since tcp/139 is not open and the client tries to connect via SMB tcp/445 then switches to tcp/80. I'd rather not open 139 if I don't have to.

XP workstations in the trusting domain are able to hit their server.

What am I missing to set this up?

**UPDATE: If we enable NetBIOS and open TCP/139 through the firewall, everything works so my question has changed. New question is I thought netbios was no lnoger needed for file sharing as of Win2K so why must I have this on to map a drive?